# How to check if current SQL session has uncommited changes?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, session

Say you are in SQL Developer and want to check if the current user session (i.e. your connection) has uncommitted changes.

If you quit SQL Developer, it does such a check and displays a dialog box how to proceed. I want to check it without exiting - e.g. via executing a special SQL statement or a SQL Developer action.

Ideally, it would be great if one could configure SQL Developer such that it is visually indicated if the current session is 'dirty' (i.e. has uncommited changes) - e.g. via displaying a red margin around the worksheet.

Answer (score 6):

There is also

```
SELECT dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id FROM dual;
```

which will show a transaction id if there are pending commits.

Answer (score 5):

You could check `V$TRANSACTION`. Here is an example:

```
create table t(a number);

Table created.

insert into t values (1);

1 row created.

select t.status
from v$transaction t
join v$session s
on t.ses_addr = s.saddr
where s.sid = sys_context('USERENV', 'SID');

STATUS
----------------
ACTIVE
```

After commiting:

```
commit;

Commit complete.

select t.status
from v$transaction t
join v$session s
on t.ses_addr = s.saddr
where s.sid = sys_context('USERENV', 'SID');

no rows selected
```

For this you have to grant `SELECT` privilege on `SYS.V_$TRANSACTION` and `SYS.V_$SESSION` though.

Comment: With one caveat. Select from @dblink would generate a dummy transaction with a bit of undo. It can be committed or rolled back without any impact.

Comment: Hm, I am wondering how the Oracle SQL Developer program implement its uncommitted-transaction-check (while exiting)? I mean, it does not need extra privileges.

Comment: This will not work for transactions started with `SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE NAME 'tran1';`